# Can anyone say why my code doesn't return output, yet code doesn't show any errors

Tags: dart, flutter

Here is my code; it doesn't show any errors, but it show redscreen on emulator and I didn't understand why it is

```
'import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './loginpage.dart';
void main()
{
    runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return LoginPage();
    }
}
```

Above is `main.dart`.

Below is `LoginPage.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget{
    @override
    _LoginPageState createState()=> _LoginPageState();
}
enum FormType{
    register,
    login
}
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage>{
    FormType _formType=FormType.login;
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return (_formType==FormType.login) ? gotologin() : gotoregister();
    }
    Widget gotologin(){
        return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
        Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0,right: 30.0,bottom: 50.0),
        height: 300.0,
        color: Color.fromARGB(10, 11, 40, 209),
        child: Center(
        child:Image.asset('assets/logohome1(3).png'),
        ),
        )
        ],
        ),
        );
    }
}

Widget gotoregister() {
    return Container(
    child: Text("data"),
    );
}'
```

The above is the code please say if anything wrong or some syntax mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly know error you are receiving.

I have tried your code and this is the error I receive:

```
I/flutter ( 8206): The following assertion was thrown building LoginPage(state: _LoginPageState#a1b8a):
I/flutter ( 8206): MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery.
I/flutter ( 8206): No MediaQuery ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to MediaQuery.of().
....
```

The error says that there is no `MediaQuery` widget in your ancestor chain. The `Scaffold` widget needs it.

This is solved by adding a `MaterialApp` widget that adds a `MediaQuery` to the tree:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: the above one is right but y should we use materialapp y my code doesnt worked

Comment: One more can i use two forms with different keys in one page

Comment: It should be possible. But they will be independent in terms of validation.

Comment: when i gave different keys  to two different forms first form works fine but second form gives a error when i assing a key

Comment: Could you explain it in a different question?